# First Wedding - What to charge?

Tags: wedding

I have been asked to shoot a wedding for one of my co-workers. I am not a professional but the bride to be has see some of my pics from parties and such and she really liked my style. This will be an outdoorsy in a barn type wedding. I live in SW Florida and plan to make 2 trips (about 50 miles each way) to the venue - one before the wedding to scope it out and take casual family and bride & groom pics, then the 2nd time for the actual wedding. My thought is that I will give them everything I shoot on DVDs and will touch up a few of their favorites if they need touching up. As I'm not a professional and have no intention to do any other weddings - what are people's general thoughts of what to charge? I was thinking $500. Is that too much?

Comment: There's some extremely similar questions already on the site - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30205/how-much-do-i-charge-for-the-first-time-wedding-photo-shoot?rq=1 and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39917/i-keep-getting-asked-to-do-wedding-photography-what-is-a-fair-price-to-ask?rq=1 for example.  This very well may get closed as a duplicate of them.  Regardless of that, I *HIGHLY* encourage you to make a contract, in writing, about your deliverables and your pay.

Comment: Look online for some example contracts. Even if you're good friends with the family you don't want to run into issues.